# Any tool to create graphs from data of a tree?

Tags: django, python-3.x

is there any simply and easy to use tool for Django (or for python) which is going to create a nice graphicon from the datas of a tree? Of course i can format the datas in any way, i just need a program which can process it and create a graphicon for it, like:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#/media/File:Binary_tree.svg

. It' s only a tree, no circle inside. Actually i' m using django-treenode .

Thanks for any tip, idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 tools which could be good:

ete3
anytree

. Unfortunately with ete3 i could not draw the graphs i needed (it always added empty nodes), however anytree works very fine (except that i can' t color the nodes at the moment).

Some snippet:

```
from anytree import Node
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter
r = Node(self._create_graph_get_gr_repr(), cnn=self)
self._create_graph_add_children(r, level)
DotExporter(r).to_picture('/tmp/gr.png')
```

.